# Graph API Subscription for New Users

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm having trouble figuring out the resource and/or change type in order to create a subscription to newly created users.  Here's what I have:

```json
    {
      "changeType": "created",
      "notificationUrl": "<someURL.com>",
      "resource": "/users",
      "expirationDateTime": "<todays date + 3>",
      "clientState": "SecretClientState"
    }
```

I'm getting back the following error:

```json
    {
      "error": {
        "code": "InvalidRequest",
        "message": "Invalid 'changeType' attribute: 'created'.",
        "innerError": {
          "date": "2021-03-12T22:24:06",
          "request-id": "51a191c2-a13e-4c63-a5ca-17923dd783cb",
          "client-request-id": "51a191c2-a13e-4c63-a5ca-17923dd783cb"
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: can you try changing "resource": "/users" to "resource": "users/",

Comment: That returns the same error

Comment: Try giving `"resource": "users"`

Comment: This returns the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation the correct value of `changeType` for users resource should be `updated`.

> Note: Drive root item and list change notifications support only the
> updated changeType. **User** and group change notifications support
> **updated** and **deleted** changeType.

Also the correct value for resource should be `users`.

```
{
  "changeType": "updated",
  "notificationUrl": "<someURL.com>",
  "resource": "users",
  "expirationDateTime": "<todays date + 3>",
  "clientState": "SecretClientState"
}
```

[Subscription resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/subscription?view=graph-rest-1.0)

[Create subscription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/subscription-post-subscriptions?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

[Additional notifications for users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/known-issues#change-notifications)

Comment: I didn't even think to look at the known issues part of the documentation.  Thanks!